# Reorder CSV rows

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, html-table

I have this code which basically reads a CSV and should output a table where the CSV row content should be reordered!

Example :

`fish;4;1;33`
fish should be at 1 row column 4.

`dog;5;2;66`
dog should be at 2nd row column 5

The problem is that it doesn't print anything, neither at the console! Can you please show me where I am wrong? What modifications should I do?

My code:

```
 function processFile() {

      var fileSize = 0;
      var theFile = document.getElementById("myFile").files[0];

      if (theFile) {

           var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
           var headerLine = "";
           var myReader = new FileReader();

           myReader.onload = function(e) {

                var content = myReader.result;
                var lines = content.split("\r");

                for (var i = 0; i <lines.length; i++)
                {
                    document.write("<th>");
                    document.write("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
                    document.write("</th>");
                }
                for (var i = 0; i <lines.length; i++)
                {  
                    document.write("<tr>");
                         for (var j = 0; j <lines.length; j++)
                         {   
                         document.write("<td>");
                         document.write("&nbsp;");
                         document.write("</td>");
                         }
                    document.write("</tr>");
                 }

                 function insertData(id, content) {

                     var dataRows = content.split("\r");
                     if (table) {
                         dataRows.forEach(function(s) {
                              var x = s.split(';');
                              table.rows[x[2]].cells[x[1]].textContent = x[0];
                         });
                      }
                }
           }
           myReader.readAsText(theFile);
      }
      return false;
 } //end
```

Comment: First of all, you should separate the parsing, and the render in 2 disctinct functions.

Comment: Second of all, you should eradicate `document.write()` from your brain. This function does not exist \*Jedi hand gesture\*. Seriously, it is the worst way to get content onto a page *by far* and you should not be using it for anything. Third of all, use a CSV parser. `.split(';')` is not good enough for CSV.

Comment: @Tomalak hahah thanks can you suggest an answer I would appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

So, i did everything again for you with a big example.
I think you can handle it in your code, or take mine in the example.

Here are the main functions you can safely use in your case :

```
        //for swapping values
        function swap(arr, a, b){
            var tmp = arr[a];
            arr[a] = arr[b];
            arr[b] = tmp;
            return arr;
        }

        //for reorder lines a<=>b
        function reorderLine(csvArray,a,b){
            return swap(csvArray,a,b);
        }

        //for reorder one col values a<=>b
        function reorderColumn(csvLine,a,b){
            return swap(csvLine.split(";"),a,b).join(';');
        }   

        // create a table with csv data
        function csvArrayToTable(csvArray,selectorId){
            var html = ["<table cellpadding='10' border='1'>"];
            csvArray.map(function(lines){
                html.push("<tr>");
                var cols = lines.split(";");
                html.push("<th>"+cols[0]+"</th>");
                cols.shift();
                cols.map(function(val){
                    html.push("<td>"+val+"</td>");
                });
                html.push("</tr>");
            });
            html.push("</table>");
            document.getElementById(selectorId).innerHTML = html.join('');
        }
```

And a working example you can use too, upload file is included (click on **Run code snippet** at the bottom of the post, and full page to test) :

```js
//for swapping values
function swap(arr, a, b){
 var tmp = arr[a];
 arr[a] = arr[b];
 arr[b] = tmp;
 return arr;
}

//for reorder lines a<=>b
function reorderLine(csvArray,a,b){
 console.log('reorderLine',csvArray,a,b);
 return swap(csvArray,a,b);
}

//for reorder one col values a<=>b
function reorderColumn(csvLine,a,b){
 console.log('reorderColumn',csvLine,a,b);
 return swap(csvLine.split(";"),a,b).join(';');
} 

// create a table with csv data
function csvArrayToTable(csvArray,selectorId){
 var html = ["<table cellpadding='10' border='1'>"];
 csvArray.map(function(lines){
  html.push("<tr>");
  var cols = lines.split(";");
  html.push("<th>"+cols[0]+"</th>");
  cols.shift();
  cols.map(function(val){
   html.push("<td>"+val+"</td>");
  });
  html.push("</tr>");
 });
 html.push("</table>");
 document.getElementById(selectorId).innerHTML = html.join('');
}

// init element
var rawCsvFile = document.getElementById("csvInput");
var rawCsv = document.getElementById("rawCsv");
var reorderedRawCsv = document.getElementById("reorderedRawCsv");
var lines = document.getElementById("lines");
var lineA = document.getElementById("lineA");
var lineB = document.getElementById("lineB");
var colA = document.getElementById("colA");
var colB = document.getElementById("colB");
var apply = document.getElementById("apply");
var reset = document.getElementById("reset");
var rawCsvData, reorderCsvData;

// file uploaded
rawCsvFile.addEventListener("change", function() {

 // reader
 var reader = new FileReader();



 // the file is loaded
 reader.onload = function(e) {

  // cancel if undefined
  if(!reader.result || typeof reader.result != "string") return;

  // Get result from new FileReader()
  rawCsvData = reader.result.split(/[\r\n]+/g); // split lines
  rawCsv.innerHTML = reader.result; // show in textarea
  reorderedRawCsvData = rawCsvData; // clone data at start

  function showCsvValueInForm(){

   // empty fields
   lines.innerHTML = "";
   lineA.innerHTML = "";
   lineB.innerHTML = "";
   colA.innerHTML = "";
   colB.innerHTML = "";

   // Show in Raw CSV textarea
   reorderedRawCsv.innerHTML = reorderedRawCsvData.join("\r\n");

   // Add All option in On
   var toAll = document.createElement('option');
   toAll.value = "all";
   toAll.innerHTML = "All";
   lines.appendChild(toAll);

   // handle line change
   reorderedRawCsvData.map(function(val,i){    
    var lineOpt = document.createElement('option');
    lineOpt.value = i;
    lineOpt.innerHTML = i + " - " +(val.split(';'))[0];
    // add options in line selects
    lines.appendChild(lineOpt.cloneNode(!!1));
    lineA.appendChild(lineOpt.cloneNode(!!1));
    lineB.appendChild(lineOpt);
   });

   // handle col change
   var nCol = rawCsvData[0].split(';');
   nCol.map(function(val,i){
    var colOpt = document.createElement('option');
    colOpt.value = i;
    colOpt.innerHTML = i;
    // add options in col selects
    colA.appendChild(colOpt.cloneNode(!!1));
    colB.appendChild(colOpt);
   });

   // create table
   csvArrayToTable(reorderedRawCsvData,"reorderedCsvTable");

  }

  // fill select, option and table with the reordered csv data
  showCsvValueInForm();

  // apply event, change the order
  apply.addEventListener("click", function() {

   // reordering line
   var lineAOpt = lineA.options[lineA.selectedIndex].value;
   var lineBOpt = lineB.options[lineB.selectedIndex].value;
   if(lineAOpt !== lineBOpt) reorderedRawCsvData = reorderLine(reorderedRawCsvData,lineAOpt,lineBOpt);

   // reordering col (all or only one)
   var colAOpt = colA.options[colA.selectedIndex].value;
   var colBOpt = colB.options[colB.selectedIndex].value;
   if(colAOpt !== colBOpt)
    if(lines.value == "all"){
     reorderedRawCsvData = reorderedRawCsvData.map(function(val,i){
      return reorderColumn(val,colAOpt,colBOpt);
     });
    }else{
       reorderedRawCsvData[lines.value] = reorderColumn(reorderedRawCsvData[lines.value],colAOpt,colBOpt);
    }

   // fill again
   showCsvValueInForm();

  });

  // reset the form with raw values
  reset.addEventListener("click", function() {

   if (confirm("Are you sure ?")) {
    // reset
    reorderedRawCsvData = rawCsvData;
    // fill again
    showCsvValueInForm();
   }

  });

 }

 // read the uploaded csv file as text
 reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0], 'utf-8');

});
```

```css
body { padding:10px; background:#eee; text-align: left; font-family: sans-serif; }
fieldset { width:80%;  background:#fff; }
```

```html
<html>

 <head>
  <title>CSV Reorder</title>

 </head>
 
 
 <body>
  
  <h1>Reorder CSV</h1>
  <fieldset>
   <h3>Step 1 - Raw CSV</h3>
   <small>Load a CSV file (not nested)</small>
   <br />
   <input type="file" id="csvInput">
   <br />
   <br />
   <div>
    <textarea id="rawCsv" placeholder="Waiting for a file..."></textarea>
   </div>
  </fieldset>
  <br />
  
  <fieldset>
   <h3>Step 2 - Reordering Option</h3>
   <small>Choose how to order the CSV data</small>
   <br />
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td>Line</td>
     <td><select id="lineA"></select></td>
     <td><=></td>
     <td><select id="lineB"></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Column</td>
     <td><select id="colA"></select></td>
     <td><=></td>
     <td><select id="colB"></select></td>
     <td>on</td>
     <td><select id="lines"></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="4"><button id="apply">Apply</button>&nbsp;<button id="reset">Reset</button></td>
    </tr>
   </table> 
  </fieldset>
  <br />

  <fieldset>
   <h3>Step 3 - Reordered CSV</h3>
   <small>Get the reordered values</small>
   <br />
   <div>
   <textarea id="reorderedRawCsv" placeholder="Waiting for options..."></textarea>
   </div>
   <div>
    <h3>Reordered CSV in a table</h3>
    <div id="reorderedCsvTable">
     <small>Waiting for a file..</small>
     <br />
    </div>
   </div>
  </fieldset>
   
 
 </body>
</html>
```

Enjoy !